# free MATLAB environment

Tags: matlab

I'm learning the MATLAB language and would like to have some kind of free environment to experiment with. The MATLAB environment provided by MathWorks is commercial. There appears to be a trial available, but I can't figure out how to get the trial license.

For the moment, all I need is a command-line and the "standard libraries".

Comment: Note that you can request a trial here: http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/tryit.html

Answer (score 16):

Octave is mostly compatible with matlab: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Comment: I like Octave's noninteractive capabilities (good compatibility) which is what the OP wants. MATLAB is way better for GUI + debugging + profiling, though.

Answer (score 10):

If you are just starting with MATLAB I would strongly suggest to go the [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) path instead (unless there is some very specific reason why you must use MATLAB). The basics (like array / matrix operations) are very similar to MATLAB.

In my current area of work (neuroscience) there is a strong migration from MATLAB to Python. Many groups are making the switch because Python is free and generally more powerful.

The basic packages you will probably need to get started would be [numpy](https://numpy.org/) (basic array numerics), [scipy](https://scipy.org/) (more algorithms) and [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) (plotting). Since you want to work on the command line I suggest [IPython](https://web.archive.org/web/20110823082301/http://ipython.scipy.org:80/moin) as well.

As already mentioned in another answer there are also some Python distributions which include many packages, like [PythonXY](https://pythonxy.com/), the [Enthought Python Distribution](https://web.archive.org/web/20130403011619/http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php), or [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution).

There are many tutorials available on the web, search a little and pick one you like.

Comment: I second that.  I am essentially leaving Matlab after hundreds of thousands of lines of code.  Python is now very competitive with Matlab and the community of Matlab refugees using Python is growing all the time.  R is great, too, but the choice depends on usage.

Comment: Note that with [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) you can also use R nicely with Python.

Comment: That is true, and a good point (there's also rpy2).  I connected Matlab and R (usually calling R from Matlab) quite a bit, and it's a wise idea to know how to do it from Python.  There's no sense in re-inventing the wheel in a new language.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot agree on the Python part. Python still lacks the kind of massive documentation that Matlab has. It lacks on the graphics part as well. Of course, it has its own merits - the programming side is much better (Threads, powerful language). But overall, in my humble opinion, I used both and I cannot agree with you.

Comment: @Andrey: What kind of graphics do you miss in particular?

Answer (score 6):

Look into these:

- [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/)
- [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)
- [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/index.html)

Read [this blog entry from Ryan Morlok](http://www.morlok.net/ryan/2006/11/01/open-source-matlab-alternatives/) for more info on open source Matlab alternatives.

I'm a big fan of [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_programming_language), but it's not a substitute for Matlab... it's an alternative. There's a big difference!

Comment: FWIW, there's an interface for calling R from MATLAB and vice versa.  One could even conceive of calling an R function from MATLAB that in turn calls an R function, but why you'd ever design something that way is beyond me.

Comment: That's very Perl-esque... more than one way to do things. Thanks for pointing me to that.

Answer (score 3):

I was recently enamoured of Python XY.  It's not exactly like Matlab but it has many of the same functions and copies the look and feel.  I would personally use it if I didn't want to buy a Matlab license though - not if I wanted to practice with a Matlab stand-in.

[www.pythonxy.com](http://www.pythonxy.com/"PythonXY")

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in trying things out in MATLAB directly, there was [a recent blog entry on The MathWorks website](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/03/02/free-toolboxes/) regarding free trial downloads of MATLAB and its various toolboxes. If you haven't tried contacting them already, the blog links to [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/downloads/web_downloads/trials?s_cid=pl_trials) where you can request product trials or, if you already have a licensed product, you can sign in and downloads trials of toolboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Other users have given you the examples that I would have suggested - Octave and Scilab.  Of the two, I would say that Scilab is more powerful BUT Octave tries really hard to be source compatible with standard MATLAB and Scilab does not.

So, if your aim is to experiment with a MATLAB like language and learn skills that you will eventually be able to transfer over to MATLAB then I suggest that you stick with Octave.