# Any open source software like matlab?

Tags: open-source, matlab

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [free matlab environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571985/free-matlab-environment)
>   [What’s the best MATLAB equivalent? (open source or otherwise free)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072884/whats-the-best-matlab-equivalent-open-source-or-otherwise-free)

Please suggest any open source/free software equivalent to Matlab for windows with same syntax which is best and widely used

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072884/whats-the-best-matlab-equivalent-open-source-or-otherwise-free

Comment: FreeMat , "FreeMat is a free environment for rapid engineering and scientific prototyping and data processing. It is similar to commercial systems such as MATLAB from Mathworks, and IDL from Research Systems, but is Open Source. FreeMat is available under the GPL license."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the obvious choices for MATLAB alternatives:

- [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)
- [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/)
- [Python](http://www.python.org/) + [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) + [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) + [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)
- [R](https://www.r-project.org/)
- [FreeMat](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/)

And here's a number of similar environments:

- [RLab](http://rlab.sourceforge.net/) *[discontinued]*
- [Mathnium](http://www.mathnium.com/) *(Freeware)*
- [Sysquake LE](http://www.calerga.com/products/Sysquake/index.html) *(Freeware)*
- [O-Matrix](http://www.omatrix.com/) *(Commercial)*

Comment: You might want to add sage (http://www.sagemath.org/) to that list, since it'll do a lot of the symbolic stuff that others won't.

Answer (score 9):

GNU Octave is the closest replacement, it supports large parts of the Matlab syntax, plus incorporates several improvements (IMHO) to the language.

But if you are familiar with **python** I suggest you also take a look at **[SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/)**. Powerful language, a lot of libraries, and active development in scientific libraries ([plotting](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), calculus, etc.). Use the [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/FrontPage?action=show&redirect=VoorPagina) interactive shell.

Comment: Can you expand on what you consider to be the improvements?  (I'm just curious.)  Thanks!

Comment: Well it has been a long time since I used octave, but if I remember correctly octave allows to access matrix elements directly returned by a function, e.g.: `magic(5)(1,1)`. Matlab requires temporary variables.

Answer (score 5):

[octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is mostly compatible with matlab.  You can read more about the differences [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/FAQ.html#MATLAB-compatibility).

Answer (score 2):

Octave is a free Matlab-like program that a lot of people seem to like.

This site has a whole list of free alternatives:
http://www.math.tu-berlin.de/~ehrhardt/matlab_alternatives.html

Answer (score 1):

While studying in the University, I personally used [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) for al my lab and course papers calculations :-) What I love about it, is that you don't need to learn new language if you know python already.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular alternatives are: Octave and Scilab (www.scilab.org).